# Getting a book genres and language scraped from goodreads using beautifulsoup

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I was trying to scape a book metadat from goodreads but, i can't get it right for geners and language
here are the code

```
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from argparse import Namespace
from urllib.request import urlopen
import pandas as pd


def get_genres(soup):
    genres = []
    for node in soup.find_all('div', {'class': 'left'}):
        current_genres = node.find_all('a', {'class': 'actionLinkLite bookPageGenreLink'})
        current_genre = ' > '.join([g.text for g in current_genres])
        if current_genre.strip():
            genres.append(current_genre)
    return genres




def scrape_book(book_id: str, args: Namespace):
    url = "https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/" + book_id
    source = urlopen(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(source, "html.parser")

    book = {
        "book_id_title": book_id,
        "book_id": get_id(book_id),
        "book_title": soup.find("h1", {"class": "Text Text__title1", "data-testid":"bookTitle"}).text,
        "book_description": soup.find("span", {"class": "Formatted"}).text,
        "book_url": url,
        "Book_work_pages": soup.find("p", {"data-testid": "pagesFormat"}).text,
        "Book_work_published_date": soup.find("p", {"data-testid": "publicationInfo"}).text,
        "book_author": soup.find("span", {"class": "ContributorLink__name"}).text,
        "book_author_url": soup.find("a", {"class": "ContributorLink"}).text,
        "book_language": soup.find("div", {"class": "TruncatedContent" }).text,
        "genres": get_genres(soup)
        
    }

    return book

scrape_book (book_id='343', args= Namespace)
```

this is the book page in the above code
https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/343

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try CSS selector `a[href*="/genres/"]`: This selects all `<a>` tags containing `/genres/` in the `href=` attribute:

```py
def get_genres(soup):
    genres = []
    for a in soup.select('a[href*="/genres/"]'):
        genres.append(a.text)
    return genres
```

This will select these genres from the URL:

```
['Fiction', 'Classics', 'Historical Fiction', 'Horror', 'Mystery', 'Thriller', 'Crime']
```

Comment: It works very well, Thanks Andrij for your answer, But what about the language part, I couldn't figure out the nested dive part